# Remove a block from layout without a name

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, blocks

I want to remove a block from the layout in magento 2 that is declared in a third party extension, but the block does not have a name.
Can I do that?

The block is declared like this

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="[Vendor_Module]::template.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I cannot use

```
<referenceBlock name="..." remove="true" />
```

because, as you can see there is no name on it.

Comment: marius, i  have idea.if we  using  event and remove block  by match template name  `[Vendor_Module]::template.phtml`

Comment: I have the same idea (see comments on the answer) but I will use it only as a desperate measure. I was hoping for a simple solution. If you have some code, post it as an answer.

Comment: ha  ha that we donot have  simple solution.let me try  give u an answer using event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an idea from [Amit's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206785/146) and ended up with a working solution that does not look very intrusive and it's not an overkill since my code is executed only once.

I've created an observer on the event `layout_generate_blocks_after` that is executed after the layouts are loaded and the blocks are generated.

This can have a drawback because the block I'm trying to remove still gets instantiated, but in my case I just needed to remove it from the page.

So I have the file `etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="remove-the-block" instance="[MyVendor]\[MyModule]\Observer\RemoveBlock" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and my observer class:

```
<?php
namespace [MyVendor]\[MyModule]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemoveBlock implements ObserverInterface
{
    const TEMPLATE_TO_REMOVE = '[OtherVendor]_[OtherModule]::template.phtml';
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $blocks = $layout->getAllBlocks();
        foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
            if ($block->getTemplate() == self::TEMPLATE_TO_REMOVE) {
                $layout->unsetElement($key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this issue in class `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure\Helper`

There is function `_generateAnonymousName`:

```
protected function _generateAnonymousName($class)
{
    $position = strpos($class, '\\Block\\');
    $key = $position !== false ? substr($class, $position + 7) : $class;
    $key = strtolower(trim($key, '_'));
    return $key . $this->counter++;
}
```

It's call from `scheduleStructure` function:

```
    public function scheduleStructure(
    Layout\ScheduledStructure $scheduledStructure,
    Layout\Element $currentNode,
    Layout\Element $parentNode
) {
    // if it hasn't a name it must be generated
    if (!(string)$currentNode->getAttribute('name')) {
        $name = $this->_generateAnonymousName($parentNode->getElementName() . '_schedule_block'); // CALL HERE
        $currentNode->setAttribute('name', $name);
    }
    $path = $name = (string)$currentNode->getAttribute('name');

    // Prepare scheduled element with default parameters [type, alias, parentName, siblingName, isAfter]
    $row = [
        self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_TYPE           => $currentNode->getName(),
        self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_ALIAS          => '',
        self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_PARENT_NAME    => '',
        self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_SIBLING_NAME   => null,
        self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_IS_AFTER       => true,
    ];

    $parentName = $parentNode->getElementName();
    //if this element has a parent element, there must be reset [alias, parentName, siblingName, isAfter]
    if ($parentName) {
        $row[self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_ALIAS] = (string)$currentNode->getAttribute('as');
        $row[self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_PARENT_NAME] = $parentName;

        list($row[self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_SIBLING_NAME],
            $row[self::SCHEDULED_STRUCTURE_INDEX_IS_AFTER]) = $this->_beforeAfterToSibling($currentNode);

        // materialized path for referencing nodes in the plain array of _scheduledStructure
        if ($scheduledStructure->hasPath($parentName)) {
            $path = $scheduledStructure->getPath($parentName) . '/' . $path;
        }
    }

    $this->_overrideElementWorkaround($scheduledStructure, $name, $path);
    $scheduledStructure->setPathElement($name, $path);
    $scheduledStructure->setStructureElement($name, $row);
    return $name;
}
```

With this case, Block name can be:

- `before.body.end_schedule_block1`
- `before.body.end_schedule_block2`
- ...

I think you should define totals block without the name on container and order block name need remove on the container.

Comment: I don't think this will work. There is no way to predict the generated name since on different pages there can be multiple blocks added in the `body.before.end` container in different order.

Comment: This case only applies to block/container without a name. If all of them without the name, so difficult to define some block/container need removed.

Comment: yep...my problem exactly

Comment: We should rewrite `$name = $this->_generateAnonymousName($parentNode->getElementName() . '_schedule_block');` , Should be pass class & template to parameter ?

Comment: seems like an overhead to rewrite something like that. I'm looking for a simple solution (if any) or an answer like 'not possible very easily'. I think I can observe the layout generate blocks event or something to remove it there, but again seems too much overhead. I'm keeping that as a backup solution.

Comment: that  is only solution, same situation, i have faced in paster, you cannot remove using  layout

Comment: Btw, you can fix this. Just give some name to the block and create PR on github.

Answer (score 3):

I am really give u bad idea.

Here the idea is not stop output of your block

**Using event `view_block_abstract_to_html_after`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="view_block_abstract_to_html_after">
        <observer name="myObserverName" instance="Stack\Work\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**And using this observer disable output of your block**

```
<?php
namespace Stack\Work\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //Observer initialization code...
    //You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $block = $observer->getData('block');

    if('[Vendor_Module]::template.phtml' == $block->getTemplate()){
        $transport = $observer->getData('transport');
        $transport->setHtml('');

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not actually such a bad idea. Indeed there is an overkill observing all the blocks, but I'm willing to use it over other options. I will try and let you know.

Comment: coool. man.... see what happen

Comment: It works, but I tried to optimize it a bit, not to execute the code for every block. So I ended up with [my answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206873/146).  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I see answer, that really good man :)